# Customer select

Tags: sql

I have customer table order table where I have `CustomerID` and `order date`. List the customers, giving for each the number of orders they have made as well as the
dates of the first and the last order. Sort by the number of orders.
I have just started to study SQL but I am not sure how to start.

```
SELECT customerId
      ,count(customerId)
      ,MAX(orderDate)
      ,MIN(orderDate) 
  FROM CustomerOrders
```

Comment: What did you try?  Look into using `group by`, `count`, `max`, `min` and `order by`...

Comment: Start simple. And you should at least try to show something. This site isn't for doing the work for you, it's for helping you when you get stuck. `Select * From CustomerOrders`. Start there and build on that. Also, what RDBMS are you using.

Comment: I am using https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all website to learn and using the same database. Could you give me then other good material where I can start with like in this case I guess I need to creat a new table but not sure how to make number of order that should be with count but still not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE CustomerOrders(customerId INT, orderDate DATETIME);

SELECT customerId, count(customerId), MAX(orderDate), MIN(orderDate) FROM CustomerOrders GROUP BY customerId;
```